# Gitlab CI secrets with azure key vault gives "no resolver that can handle the secret"

Tags: azure, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, azure-keyvault

Using Gitlab version `v16.8.1-ee`

I have followed the guide written at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/azure_key_vault.html to setup the proper app, service principal, and federated identity in Azure. As well as assigned the proper reader and key vault secrets user permission roles for the app.

I have confirmed and verified that I can login and access the key vault and the secrets via AZ CLI in a gitlab-ci job using the credentials generated.

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` I have the following job:

```yaml
get_az_secret:
  allow_failure: true
  when: manual
  variables:
    AZURE_KEY_VAULT_SERVER_URL: https://my-magical-keyvault.vault.azure.net
    AZURE_CLIENT_ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
    AZURE_TENANT_ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
  id_tokens:
    AZURE_JWT:
      aud: https://gitlab.my-selfhosted-domain.com
  secrets:
    TEST:
      token: $AZURE_JWT
      azure_key_vault:
        name: my-magical-secret
        version: 20ad3ea2266041d4b2f8b1eedb41b992
      file: false
  script:
    - echo $TEST
```

When the job runs, it outputs the following:

```bash
Resolving secrets
Resolving secret "TEST"...
WARNING: Not resolved: no resolver that can handle the secret
```

Gitlab's own documentation doesn't address this particular issue. Neither does Azure.

What exactly does this output warning indicate?

I have attempted to wrap the `aud`, `name`, and `version` values in quotation but that made no difference.

I have also tried different secret names and versions from the same Azure key vault.

I even tried an entirely different Azure key vault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related with the runners version.
The GCP integration was introduced in GitLab and GitLab Runner 16.8. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/442008.
I assume you are using shared runners. Since they didn't upgrade the entire fleet yet it's possible that older runners are running your pipeline.